# In pgAdmin, one CSV imports fine, but second CSV fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

I'm new to coding, and having been googling this for weeks with no luck.

In pgAdmin 4, I've successfully imported the first .CSV to my table 'amkai' (by right-clicking the table > Import/Export, Header: Yes).

Here's the CREATE statement for refernce:

```
CREATE TABLE public.amkai
(   
case_no integer NOT NULL,
acct integer NOT NULL,
dos date,
pt_lastname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
pt_firstname character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
primary_proc character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
primary_proc_desc character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
doctor character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
or_min integer,
room character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
anest_type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
CONSTRAINT amkai_pkey PRIMARY KEY (case_no)
)
```

But when I try to import another .CSV to another table 'envi' on the same database, I keep getting "Failed (exit code: 1)" and data does not import. Nothing shows up in the server log either.

Here's the CREATE statement for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE public.envi
(
usage_no integer NOT NULL,
case_no integer,
acct integer,
facility_no character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
usage_type character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
usage_date date,
date_submitted date,
line_item_no integer,
item_no character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
item_desc character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
vendor_no character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
vendor character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
vendor_item_no character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
manufacturer character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
manufacturer_item_no character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
item_type character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
system_type character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
classification character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
classification2 character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
ar_billing_code character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
qty integer,
uom character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
conversion_factor integer,
unit_cost numeric(12, 4),
ext_cost numeric(12, 4),
unit_price numeric(12, 4),
is_billable boolean,
expense_ledger_no integer,
dept_gl_code integer,
location_gl_code integer,
dos date,
primary_proc character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
primary_proc_desc character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
doctor character varying (255) COLLATE pg_catalog.default,
or_mins integer,
CONSTRAINT envi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (usage_no),
CONSTRAINT case_no FOREIGN KEY (case_no)
REFERENCES public.amkai (case_no) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

The CSV's have the same columns as my tables.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: This is not enough information. How are you doing the import? Does the CSV file have all the fields that are in the table? What is the complete error message? What shows up in the Postgres server log when you do the import?

Comment: This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you to improve your next questions